# Python - Concat two raw strings with an user name

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a raw string like this,

```
MasterFile_Name = r'C:\Users\ABC\X12345\DEF\File - Test.xlsx'
```

I want to pass the value of X12345 through a variable.To do that I am doing something like this

MyID = X12345

```
MasterFile_Name = r'C:\Users\ABC\' + MyID + '\DEF\File - Test.xlsx'
```

and

```
MasterFile_Name = r'C:\Users\ABC\' + MyID + r'\DEF\File - Test.xlsx'
```

They both are not working for me.

Kindly help me with this.

Comment: MasterFile_Name =  r'C:\Users\ABC\{}\DEF\File - Test.xlsx'.format(MyID)

Comment: you can also use f-strings if you have python 3.7+ like so: `MasterFile_Name = rf'C:\Users\ABC\{MyID}\DEF\File - Test.xlsx'`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the intention is to just concatenate it.

using [`str.format()`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-string-formatters-in-python-3):

```
MyID = 'X12345'    
MasterFile_Name = r'C:\Users\ABC\{}\DEF\File - Test.xlsx'.format(MyID)    
print(MasterFile_Name)
```

Comment: I have a `LaTeX` raw string `text = r'$QFT=\frac{1}{\sqrt{} \begin{bmatrix}'.format('128')`. The snippet throws error `IndexError: Replacement index 1 out of range for positional args tuple`.

Comment: @RajeshSwarnkar: You should use rf-format string, like ``x = 128`` and ``text = rf"$QFT=\frac{{1}}{{\sqrt{x}}} \begin{{bmatrix}}"``.